# Auto-complete popup menu: make Enter trigger newline if no item was selected

Tags: key-bindings, autocompletion, plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-neocomplete

I like using the `<CR>` key to confirm my selection in the popup menu. However I don't like the `<CR>` key doing absolutely nothing when no item was selected in the menu -- in this case, it usually means I don't want to confirm a completion, I just want to insert a newline.

My current remap

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>" : "\<CR>"
```

will "confirm the selection" and close the popup menu even if no item is selected -- i.e. the cursor stays in the same place. Is there another function I can use in the above ternary operation, or some other approach, that will give me the desired behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with a fairly hacky solution. I just remap the keys I want to use for scrolling the popup menu to also increment/decrement a counter as the menu is scrolled. If the counter is zero, we will insert a newline instead of "confirming" our choice in the popup menu. Note these were developed with the [neocomplete plugin](https://github.com/Shougo/neocomplete.vim) with the option `let g:neocomplete#enable_auto_select=0`.

I personally just use `<Tab>`/`<S-Tab>` and `<ScrollWheelUp>`/`<ScrollWheelDown>` but included some other remaps for people who prefer different keys.

```
"Reset the counter with autocmds where possible
au BufEnter * let b:tabcount=0
au InsertEnter * let b:tabcount=0
"Helper functions
function! s:tabincrease() "use this inside <expr> remaps
  let b:tabcount+=1
  return "" "returns empty string so can be used inside <expr>
endfunction
function! s:tabdecrease() "use this inside <expr> remaps
  let b:tabcount-=1
  return ""
endfunction
function! s:tabreset() "use this inside <expr> remaps
  let b:tabcount=0
  return ""
endfunction
"Map the default keys for navigating completion popup menu
inoremap <expr> <C-y> pumvisible() ? "\<C-y>".<sid>tabreset() : "\<C-y>"
inoremap <expr> <C-e> pumvisible() ? "\<C-e>".<sid>tabreset() : "\<C-e>"
inoremap <expr> <C-n> <sid>tabincrease()."\<C-n>"
inoremap <expr> <C-p> <sid>tabdecrease()."\<C-p>"
"Map custom keys for confirming/cancelling a menu selection
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? b:tabcount==0 ? "\<C-e>\<CR>" : "\<C-y>".<sid>tabreset() : "\<CR>"
inoremap <expr> <Space> pumvisible() ? "\<Space>".<sid>tabreset() : "\<Space>"
inoremap <expr> <BS> pumvisible() ? "\<C-e>\<BS>".<sid>tabreset() : "\<BS>"
"Map custom keys for scrolling through the menu
inoremap <expr> <Tab> pumvisible() ? <sid>tabincrease()."\<C-n>" : "\<Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <S-Tab> pumvisible() ? <sid>tabdecrease()."\<C-p>" : "\<S-Tab>"
inoremap <expr> <Down> pumvisible() ? <sid>tabincrease()."\<C-n>" : "\<Down>"
inoremap <expr> <Up> pumvisible() ? <sid>tabdecrease()."\<C-p>" : "\<Up>"
inoremap <expr> <ScrollWheelDown> pumvisible() ? <sid>tabincrease()."\<C-n>" : "\<ScrollWheelDown>"
inoremap <expr> <ScrollWheelUp> pumvisible() ? <sid>tabdecrease()."\<C-p>" : "\<ScrollWheelUp>"
```

Answer (score 3):

To add to existing answers, I found `empty(v:completed_item)` to be unreliable, and sometimes it will be empty even though I have something selected in the pum.

What worked for me was to use `complete_info()` and directly get the line selected. if the selected line is `-1`, then we know for sure nothing is selected.

```
pumvisible() ? (complete_info().selected == -1 ? '<C-y><CR>' : '<C-y>') : '<CR>'
```

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Good first answer.

Answer (score 1):

The following works elegantly without the need for too many bindings.

```
function! s:CRComplete()
  if empty(v:completed_item)
    execute "norm! i\<CR>"
  endif endfunction
inoremap <CR> <LEFT><RIGHT><C-O>:call <SID>CRComplete()<CR>
```

Edits: In view of Hotschke's answer, the check for `v:completed_item` in my function above is simplified.

`<LEFT><RIGHT>` is added for the situation in which omni-complete returns a `Pattern not found`.

Answer (score 0):

My version works as following

1. When pum is visible & entry selected which is a snippet, expand snippet.
2. When pum is visible & entry selected which is not a snippet, only close pum.
3. When pum is visible & no entry selected, close pum and insert newline.
4. When pum is not visible, insert newline.

```
function! s:ExpandSnippetOrClosePumOrReturnNewline()
    if pumvisible()
        if !empty(v:completed_item)
            let snippet = UltiSnips#ExpandSnippet()
            if g:ulti_expand_res > 0
                return snippet
            else
                return "\<C-y>"
            endif
        else
            return "\<C-y>\<CR>"
        endif
    else
        return "\<CR>"
    endif
endfunction
inoremap <silent> <CR> <C-r>=<SID>ExpandSnippetOrClosePumOrReturnNewline()<CR>
```

see also https://github.com/vim/vim/issues/2004